# JOGL: GLProfile.getDefault() returns GL2 when GL4 is available

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, driver, hardware, jogl

Method GLProfile.getDefault() returns GL2 when GL4 is available. Why? I use Ubuntu 17.04, proccessor is Intel Core i5-7500 (Video Adapter is Intel HD Graphics 630, and it supports GL4 (as described in specification for this Graphics Card).

Output of `glxinfo | grep -i opengl`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: [the documentation](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GLProfile.html#GL_PROFILE_LIST_ALL) says that GL2 has a higher priority than GL4 without compatibility profile. Your setup seems to only have GL4 in core profile. This is described in the [docs for getDefault](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GLProfile.html#getDefault()).

Comment: @PeterT Thank you. What I could do that `getDeafult()` returns `GL4`?

Comment: buy a graphics card that has drivers which support OpenGL4.x with compatibility mode or change the JOGL source-code. But I think you actually just want to call `getMaximum(true)` instead

Comment: PeterT is right. Use a particular profile with GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4), getMaximum, or getMaxProgrammable or getMaxProgrammableCore. I really advise you to read the documentation before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, perhaps, my videocard drivers under linux does not support GL4. (But my videocard supports it)